# Htaccess Howto Redirect old Url to new url that get new charater and remove slash in middle of new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've a problem about Redirect by htaccess.
It is all the link like this: **abc.com/cate/yyyy/mm/yyyy_postname**
Redirect to link like this: **abc.com/post-yyyymm/postname**

I was try this: 
**RedirectMatch 301 ^cate/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})_(.*)$** post-([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$1
But it not working.
Please help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use back-references on RHS of your rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cate/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})_(.*)$ /post-$1$2/$4
```

Comment: Thank to Anubhava. it is a useful

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I was click on it before post a replay. but i dont know why it ask me "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Anubhava,

Your help is useful. 
Although it not redirect to the correct url result.
It redirect to: **acb.com/post-yyyy/mm/yyyy_**

BUT It help me go deeper to understand the way to use your help.
And I was try to change like this: 
**RedirectMatch 301 ^/cate/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})_(.*)$ /post-$1$2/$4**
Haha, so crazy, that working.
It redirect exactly from link: **acb.com/cate/yyyy/mm/yyyy_postname**
To link: **acb.com/post-yyyymm/postname**

Thank again to Anubhava.